# Не работает html5 видео в мобильниках

Tags: html, html5, видео

Вставил фоном html5 видео (видео расположено локально):

**HTML**

```
</header>
    <div class="video"></div>
        <video autoplay loop>
        <source src="po_13.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
        <source src="po_13.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
        <source src="po_13.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
         Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
       </video> 
</header>
```

**Css**

```
header{
    /*background-image: url("../img/slide1.png");*/
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100px;
}

video{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    /*height: auto;*/
    z-index: -100;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}

.video{
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -99;
    /*background: #000;*/
    background:url(../images/overlay.png) repeat;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

И тут возникла проблема - видео совсем не отражается на мобильных устройствах - просто черный экран, ни на гугл хром (андройд), ни на iphone. Что я сделал не так?

**UPDATE**

я уже урезал код вот так:

```
<video>
   <source src="/po_13.mp4" type='video/mp4' ></source>
   <source src="po_13.webm" type='video/webm' ></source>
   <source src="po_13.ogg" type='video/ogg' ></source>
   Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

и все равно не работает

**UPDATE2**

```
 <video controls>
  <source src="po_13.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="po_13.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Если вставляю так, то включается плеер и при нажатии на play видео начинает проигрывается, но мне бы видос как фон поставить с loop и autoplay

Comment: Мобилки очень вредные. Делайте несколько видео одного формата, отличающихся по качеству, битрейту и прочему.

Comment: @ворон хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Возможно ли сделать автозапуск видео на телефоне, вставленного с youtube?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584130/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81-youtube)

Comment: @Crantisz вы на даты вопросов посмотрите, и скажите кто кого продублировал

Answer (score 5):

Html должен быть валидным.

```
<div class="video">
  <video autoplay="autoplay" loop>
     <source src="po_13.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
     <source src="po_13.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
     <source src="po_13.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
     Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video> 
</div>
```

В html коде страницы первый тег обязательно должен быть `<!DOCTYPE html>`.
А также в head надо указывать, например, `<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=Edge' />`

Comment: Ээээ а при чём тут тэги, и то что не работает видео?

Comment: в html коде надо соблюдать определенные правила, иначе браузеры могут просто игнорировать теги с ошибками.

Comment: ну ок, а видео почему не работает?

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов, я в комменте к вопросу написал одну из возможных причин. У нас вроде больше 20 файлов генерировалось, чтобы как можно больше мобилок охватить. Попробуйте сделать самую плохую версию файла (т.е. с минимальным разрешением и качеством звука) - если запустится, то увеличивая параметры найдете оптимальный вариант. + сам кодек для аудио тоже может не поддерживаться. Если нормальный ответ не напишут - вечером поищу ресурсы, которыми раньше пользовался. Правда, с видео года два назад работал, поэтому такой проблемы уже может и не быть

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов -- если вы взяли html из моего ответа и тоже не работает, то проверьте правильность значения src. возможно надо указать путь к файлу, а не только имя.

Comment: также попробуйте убрать codecs, т.е. останется просто type="video/mp4"

Comment: @Stack посмотрите, я обновил вопрос

Comment: а src проверили? и в html должен быть первый тег DOCTYPE и т.д. -- добавил в ответ.

Comment: @Stack посмотрите пож-та update2 в вопросе

Comment: попробуйте заменить autoplay -- добавил в ответ.

Comment: нет....не работает

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов  autoplay отключен на iOS devices. см. [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12496184/5673266)

Answer (score 1):

Функция автовоспроизведения видео специально отключена на мобильных устройствах. Вот, например, что по этому поводу [пишет Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html):

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may
> be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and
> autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.

Аналогично в Android 4.1+ тоже отключен автоплей.
Одним, словом, производители смартфонов озаботились о том, чтобы пользователи не тратили слишком много мобильного интернета.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте это в свой код и видео будет работать на телефоне.

`video autoplay loop muted playsinline webkit-playinginline`

Comment: Мне помогло данное решение, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же проблема получилась, только у меня видео не фоном, а просто располагаются на странице... решил добавлением **controls**. При этом на страницах с ПК видео проигрываются автоматически, а на мобильных устройствах их нужно включать вручную. Оказывается мобильные устройства плохо относятся к **autoplay** видео.

```
<video loop muted controls autoplay preload="auto" poster="assets/video/video1.jpg">
  <source src="assets/video/video1.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  <source src="assets/video/video1.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
  <source src="assets/video/vodeo1.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
```

Мои видео - это бывшие флеш-ролики без звука, поэтому добавлен параметр **muted**. Все параметры, кроме **preload** могут быть без передаваемых параметров, это корректно.

Ставил опыты, действительно, от валидности сконвертированного видео многое зависит (невадиное не проигрывается).

Answer (score 0):

Вот так будет валидно, попробуйте так, и проблем с плерами быть не должно

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: Что именно будет валидно? Разверните свой ответ.