# Возможно ли сделать автозапуск видео на телефоне, вставленного с youtube?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Для того, чтобы сделать автозапуск видео, [вставленного](http://%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80.%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%B6-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F.%D1%80%D1%84/tatuaj2000-foto/) с youtube, нужно установить параметр autoplay=1. На телефоне автозапуск не работает. Возможно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция автовоспроизведения видео специально отключена на мобильных устройствах. Вот, например, что по этому поводу [пишет Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html):

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may
> be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and
> autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.

Аналогично в Android 4.1+ тоже отключен автоплей.
Одним, словом, производители смартфонов озаботились о том, чтобы пользователи не тратили слишком много мобильного интернета.

Answer (score 1):

Автозапуск видео на `iOS` и `Android` сделать невозможно сделать на 100%.

---

Есть [**"хаки"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009888/autoplay-audio-files-on-an-ipad-with-html5), которые срабатывают, но все зависит от версии операционной системы мобильного устройства, что нельзя назвать универсальным решением, так что ответ - **нельзя сделать автозапуск видео**.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать автозапуск видео достаточно стабильный. Правда, для этого, видео должно быть не на youtube, а загружено на ваш сервер или dropbox. Гуглите "фоновое видео в zero block", вот одно из решений: https://madeon.pro/back-video

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитаты или документацию, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке] (/help/how-to-answer).